# Two approaches of computing a $\mathrm{Tor}$-functor give different results. Which one goes wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, homological-algebra

I'm comming up with the following execise:

**Exercise**: Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is an $R$-module via the map $\epsilon: \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ sending $X$ to zero. Compute $\mathrm{Tor}_{i}^R(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$.

My friends and I came up with two approaches computing it, but derived different result. We are confused that which one goes wrong.

---

**Approach 1**: Starting with the Koszul complex
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X] \xrightarrow{\times X} \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0,
$$
regarded as a free (hence projecitve) resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then applying the functor $- \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z}$, we have a chain complex
$$
\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]}\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times X} \mathbb{Z}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.
$$
By canonical isomorphisms, we see this is merely
$$
\cdots 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times X} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.
$$
Now as $X$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}$ by zero by definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[X]$-module. Therefore, the "$\times X$" is actually the zero map. Hence
$$
\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}.
$$

---

**Approach 2**: Starting with the short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow (X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.
$$
We apply the functor $-\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z}$ to obtain a long exact sequence. Here we use the following part:
$$
0 = \mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb{Z}[X]}_{1}(\mathbb{Z}[X], \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb{Z}[X]}_{1}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow (X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \cdots.
$$
Now one computes $(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z} = 0$: Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, then
$$
(f \cdot X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} n = f \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} (X \cdot n) = 0, \qquad \forall f \in \mathbb{Z}[X], n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Therefore, we see from the exact sequence that
$$
\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0.
$$

---

So which approach contains a mistake? Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: $(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z} [X]} \mathbb{Z} \ne 0$. After all, $(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} [X]$ as modules.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you! I'm also having a doubt here. Yet the computation $$(f \cdot X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} n = f \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} (X \cdot n) = 0$$ makes $(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X]} \mathbb{Z} = 0$ quite convicing?

Comment: You can’t move $X$ across $\otimes$ like that when it denotes the generator of $(X)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ah, since $f$ may no longer lie in $(X)$?

Comment: You can think of it that way if you like, but that's not how I think of it.

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry but could you elaborate more on how you think of it?

Comment: In the first place the tensor law is $a m \otimes n = m \otimes a n$ where $m$ and $n$ are elements of possibly different modules. The roles of $a$ and $m$ are not interchangeable.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you. This is clearer!